# Join 3 tables with Laravel isn't working for me

Tags: php, mysql, join, laravel-5, eloquent

I need to get a list of failed jobs based on a "jobs" table, joined with a "prealerts" table. The only intermediary is the "packages" table which shares one column with "prealerts" and another one with "jobs".

The structure is this:

[All the structure mentioned before is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hetCV.png)

***filters.blade.php:*** (There's a checkbox here)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="failed" id="failedJobs" value="true"/>
```

And what I tried to do is:

***JobRepositoriy.php:***

```
public function search(array $filters = [])
{
.
.
.
.

    $query = $this->model
            ->select('jobs.*')
            ->distinct();

.
.
.
.

    if (isset($filters['failed']) && $filters['failed']){
            $query->ofSuccess(false);
    }


    return $query->orderBy('jobs.id', 'desc');
}
```

***jobs.php (model):***

```
 public function scopeOfSuccess($query, $success){
    return $query->join('packages', 'packages.job_id', '=', 'jobs.id')
        ->join('prealerts', 'prealerts.package_id', '=', 'packages.id')
        ->where('prealerts.created_at', '>=', '2017-01-01 00:00:00')
        ->where('prealerts.success', $success);
}
```

However, the shown results don't meet the before mentioned requirements.

Comment: I used Laravel before, don't recommend it, to be honest. It's a new framework with insufficient guidance on some topics. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: What is the result you're getting now?

Comment: @californium It's the requirement of my job. I hate laravel too haha

Comment: I need to filter results and those don't get filtered as I want. I need to get only the results where prealerts.success = false but that table must be joined to "jobs" and not viceversa. @IvankaTodorova

Comment: I'm praying for you, mate! Hated every moment of development when I used Laravel.